# Downloading ImageMagick for MediaWiki error: failed dependencies

Tags: php, centos, imagemagick, mediawiki

I am trying to install ImageMagick for MediaWiki on my website and have run into some errors. Here is some information about the things that I'm using:

Bluehost server using cpanel, as well as a Linux x86_64 system (From what I've read Bluehost uses CentOS).

My current version of MediaWiki is 1.38.1

The convert folder that I used is, well, well, under usr/bin/convert

Per what I got from the instructions from the ImageMagick website I downloaded the rpm file: `ImageMagick-7.1.0-48.x86_64.rpm`. I then put uploaded the file to the convert folder. I then ran this command as instructed from the website: `$ rpm -Uvh ImageMagick-7.1.0-48.x86_64.rpm`. When I ran it it gave me this error:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    ImageMagick-libs(x86-64) = 7.1.0-48 is needed by ImageMagick-7.1.0-48.x86_64
    libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.so.10()(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-7.1.0-48.x86_64
    libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.so.10()(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-7.1.0-48.x86_64
    libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.so.10(VERS_10.0)(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-7.1.0-48.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.34)(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-7.1.0-48.x86_64
    rpmlib(PayloadIsZstd) <= 5.4.18-1 is needed by ImageMagick-7.1.0-48.x86_64
    libMagickCore.so.5()(64bit) is needed by (installed) ea-ruby24-rubygem-rmagick-2.16.0-1.el6.eig.x86_64
    libMagickCore.so.5()(64bit) is needed by (installed) rubygem-rmagick-2.15.4-1.el6.hg.x86_64
    libMagickCore.so.5()(64bit) is needed by (installed) ea-php72-php-imagick-3.4.3-4.el6.eig.x86_64
    libMagickCore.so.5()(64bit) is needed by (installed) ea-php73-php-imagick-3.4.3-4.el6.eig.x86_64
    libMagickCore.so.5()(64bit) is needed by (installed) ea-php74-php-imagick-3.4.3-4.el6.eig.x86_64
    libMagickCore.so.5()(64bit) is needed by (installed) ImageMagick-perl-6.7.2.7-7.el6.x86_64
    libMagickWand.so.5()(64bit) is needed by (installed) ea-php72-php-imagick-3.4.3-4.el6.eig.x86_64
    libMagickWand.so.5()(64bit) is needed by (installed) ea-php73-php-imagick-3.4.3-4.el6.eig.x86_64
    libMagickWand.so.5()(64bit) is needed by (installed) ea-php74-php-imagick-3.4.3-4.el6.eig.x86_64
    ImageMagick = 6.7.2.7-7.el6 is needed by (installed) ImageMagick-perl-6.7.2.7-7.el6.x86_64
```

I then eventually figured out that I might have to download `ImageMagick-libs-7.1.0-48.x86_64.rpm` and run that first, as the command: `$ rpm -Uvh ImageMagick-libs-7.1.0-48.x86_64.rpm`. However that also gave me an error:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-libs-7.1.0-48.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-libs-7.1.0-48.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.25)(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-libs-7.1.0-48.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.33)(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-libs-7.1.0-48.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.34)(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-libs-7.1.0-48.x86_64
    libgomp.so.1(GOMP_4.5)(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-libs-7.1.0-48.x86_64
    libgs.so.9()(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-libs-7.1.0-48.x86_64
    liblcms2.so.2()(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-libs-7.1.0-48.x86_64
    liblzma.so.5()(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-libs-7.1.0-48.x86_64
    liblzma.so.5(XZ_5.0)(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-libs-7.1.0-48.x86_64
    libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.29)(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-libs-7.1.0-48.x86_64
    libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.35)(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-libs-7.1.0-48.x86_64
    libpng16.so.16()(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-libs-7.1.0-48.x86_64
    libpng16.so.16(PNG16_0)(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-libs-7.1.0-48.x86_64
    libraw_r.so.20()(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-libs-7.1.0-48.x86_64
    libtiff.so.5()(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-libs-7.1.0-48.x86_64
    libtiff.so.5(LIBTIFF_4.0)(64bit) is needed by ImageMagick-libs-7.1.0-48.x86_64
    rpmlib(PayloadIsZstd) <= 5.4.18-1 is needed by ImageMagick-libs-7.1.0-48.x86_64
```

So then I saw that the site said that if there are failed dependencies, I should go to the EPEL website and download it. So then I went on there and downloaded `epel-release-latest-9.noarch.rpm`  , and uploaded it to the convert folder. Then I tried the `rpm -Uvh epel-release-latest-9.noarch.rpm`, and it gave me this error:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    /usr/bin/bash is needed by epel-release-9-4.el9.noarch
    rpmlib(PayloadIsZstd) <= 5.4.18-1 is needed by epel-release-9-4.el9.noarch
    rpmlib(RichDependencies) <= 4.12.0-1 is needed by epel-release-9-4.el9.noarch
```

If anyone could help that'd be great, thanks

Edit: I figured out that ImageMagick is already installed on my server because, where the extension UploadWizard requires ImageMagick to function, I found out I didn't do everything that was required to configure it that I'd missed. And after that it worked. So for now it's working. But if anyone else has this kind of problem and a solution they can put it here

Comment: If you have Centos, you can likely install IM from the distribution repos, at a release compatible with your OS, and with all dependencies solved for you.

Comment: Hello, sorry for not having responded, I thought that I had solved the issue a while back and wouldn't have to face it anymore, but now I'm facing the issue to having to download/update to a new version of IM on shared hosting. Could you explain more in depth/send a link to more info about what you're talking about? Im on CentOS 6 but need to use 7.1.0 47 or later because I need to fix a TIFF handling problem. Thanks.

Comment: Using any recent software on RedHat or CentOS leads to a dependencies avalanche because they freeze the code well before the distro is published. Your best bet is to find a self-contained package (AppImage) or find/build a docker container. Incidentally, CentOS6 seems out of service by now.